# Problem with running locally with dockers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm following a google video to start a google cloud project with vscode and it throws me an error and I can't solve it

this is the video just in case https://youtu.be/EtMIEtLQNa0?t=298

````
Starting to run the app using configuration 'Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally' from .vscode/launch.json...
To view more detailed logs, go to Output channel : "Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally - Detailed"
Dependency check started
Dependency check succeeded
Unpausing minikube
The minikube profile 'cloud-run-dev-internal' has been scheduled to stop automatically after exiting Cloud Code. To disable this on future deployments, set autoStop to false in your launch configuration c:\Users\Franco\Desktop\proyecto\Proyecto Agenda Web\.vscode\launch.json
Configuring minikube gcp-auth addon
Using GCP project 'proyecto-agenda-web' with minikube gcp-auth

invalid skaffold config: source: C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Temp\cloud-code-cloud-run-iixzxH\skaffold.yaml, in module "proyecto-agenda-web" on line 7 column 14: source: C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Temp\cloud-code-cloud-run-iixzxH\skaffold.yaml, in module "proyecto-agenda-web" on line 7 column 14: invalid image "Proyecto Agenda Web": invalid reference format
source: C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Temp\cloud-code-cloud-run-iixzxH\skaffold.yaml, in module "proyecto-agenda-web" on line 7 column 14: source: C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Temp\cloud-code-cloud-run-iixzxH\skaffold.yaml, in module "proyecto-agenda-web" on line 7 column 14: invalid image "Proyecto Agenda Web": invalid reference format
Skaffold exited with code 1.
Cleaning up...
Finished clean up.```
````

I've been searching and I can't think of a solution, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The error is descriptive:

```
invalid skaffold config:
source: C:\Users\Franco\AppData\Local\Temp\cloud-code-cloud-run-iixzxH\skaffold.yaml
on line 7
column 14
invalid image "Proyecto Agenda Web"
invalid reference format
```

You have a folder called `skaffold.yaml` in that directory.

On line 7, column 14, there's probably something of the form `image: Proyecto Agenda Web` and `Projecto Agenda Web` isn't a valid container image.

These are generally of the form `some-repo/some-image:some-tag`.

You need to correct that. There may be subsequent errors.

I assume (!?) somewhere in the video, there are instructions that explain what value to use there.